# These sets are presented in lists of element form. Write the sets in the form of the set generator

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

These sets are presented in *lists of element form*. Write the sets in the form of the *set generator*

**a) {0,3,6,9,12}**

**b) {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}**

So... would the solutions be:

**a) {n*3: n=0,1,2,3,4}**

**b) {n:n ∈ Z}**

Comment: also how would I go about obtaining the solution to c) {m,n,o,p}

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Above... These sets are presented in lists of element form. Write the sets in the form of the set generator. The first a & b are the questions... the second a & b are my attempt at solving them..I'm just guessing though, I'm not really sure if I'm solving them correctly.

Comment: What is your question? Is your question "What is the answer to my homework problem"? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: My question is "is my solution correct?" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a very specific prompt, is it? There are so many options.

a. $\{n \in \mathbb N \mid n \le 12,\ 3|n \}$

b. $\{ x-1 \mid x \in \{-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\}\}$

If you wanted to get really picky, you could just say a. $\{n \mid n \in \{0,3,6,9,12\}\}$ or similar. Your answer (in your question) to part a. is correct, but b. is not. $\mathbb Z$ contains all integers, which that set from part b. certainly does not.

Comment: would my solutions be correct?

Comment: Quick question what does the "|" symbol stand for? Does that mean "such that" ?

Comment: also how in the world would I do the {m,n,o,p} one?

Comment: Yes, $\mid$ is the typical "such that" of set builder notation (except in $3|n$ where it means "3 divides n"). Your first solution is correct, your second solution is not (because $\mathbb Z \neq \{-3,-2,...,2,3\}$). I have no idea on the letters, since without an assignment they have no meaning. If this was a computer science class maybe I would recommend $\{ firstLetter(x) \mid x \in \{mom, nag, octopus, pebble\}\}$.